# Problema con useReducer y useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aplicación-web, react-hooks

Tengo un error, que realmente no encuentro porque sucede. 
Estoy trabajando un pequeño formulario en ReactJS. N
Estudiano Hooks.No me muestra el contexto en devTools. Les muestro mi App.js, el context, el reduce y el state los tengo en archivos separados. Les comparto todos los archivos.

El error que me marca es:
**./src/context/Artist/artistState.js
  Line 16:29:  React Hook "useReducer" is called in function "artistState" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

**APP.JS**

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

//Context
import artistState from "./context/Artist/artistState";
import songState from "./context/Song/songState";
import albumState from "./context/Album/albumState";

//Components
import Artists from "./components/Artists";
import Albums from "./components/Albums";
import Songs from "./components/Songs";

function App() {
  return (
    <artistState>
      <songState>
        <albumState>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4 border text-center">
                <Artists />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4 border text-center">
                <Albums />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4 border text-center">
                <Songs />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </albumState>
      </songState>
    </artistState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**artistState.js**

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

import artistContext from "./artistContext";
import artistReducer from "./artistReducer";

const artistState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    artist: "",
    number: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  };

  const prueba = () => {
    console.log("probando");
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(artistReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <artistContext.Provider value={{ prueba }}>
      {props.children}
    </artistContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default artistState;
```

**artistContext.js**

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const artistContext = createContext();

export default artistContext;
```

**artistReducer.js**

```js
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: artistContext Debería llamarse ArtistContext. Los componentes deben comenzar con una letra mayúscula

Comment: Y también artistState a ArtistState

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas Gracias